# Kettle (Pentaho PDI): concurrent write with Text File Output

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

Apparently, the *Text File Output* step of Kettle does not support concurrency: if two different *Text File Output* steps write onto the same file, no locking mechanism is implemented and thus the resulting output file contains (wrong) output rows resulting from a mix of the fields of the input sources. Can anybody provide me confirmation of this behavior (better if with a credited source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From page 387 of the book [Pentaho Kettle Solutions](http://files.hii-tech.com/book/pentaho_kettle_solutions.pdf):

> Writing to a single text file in parallel is not possible. For
>   example, you can’t use multiple  step copies of the “Text file output”
>   step to write to the same output file. If you try it,  the result is a
>   blended file with lines and fields ending up in the wrong location.
>   This  problem can only be countered with advanced locking algorithms
>   that in turn again  reduce the degree of parallelism to a single
>   thread. However, the simple solution is to write to multiple output
>   files.

Comment: u can combine streams before TextFileOutput, they should match number and type of fields in rows.

Comment: Of course. I was just wondering if the Text File Output implemented some kind of locking by itself or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing to the same files through multiple "Text file Output" steps, it is like the file is accessed by two seperate programs having separate contexts. So, of course there will be no concurrency handled by Pentaho in such cases. The file write function inside "Text file Output" is although synchronized which handles concurrency in a single context.